# Mysql between filter on convert timezone select

Tags: mysql, timezone, mariadb

Please tell me I am duplicating a question that I haven't found yet.. Here is my question.

I have a DB with all the DateTime columns stored in UTC. I want to know if I do this:

```
select CONVERT_TZ(event.startingTime,'UTC', city.timezone) as startingTime
left join city on event.cityid = city.id 
where startingTime between '2017-01-01 00:00:00' and '2017-01-01 23:59:59'
```

Is this between filter applying to the processed timezone or not? For example, imagine I have an event starting at 23:00 on UTC time, but the city is GMT+2. Will that event be listed or not? (the "raw" data in the DB is 23:00 so it should appear according to that, but once processed with the timezone is then 1:00 of the following day, so it should not appear according to this other
).

I did a test and it looks like the filter is among the "raw" data before processing, I find it hard to believe, that is why I am asking here (my mysql version is 10.0.21-MariaDB-1~wheezy)

Comment: Let me know if that worked for you :)

Comment: It's opening interesting insights. I am testing all the possible combinations, with and without timezone on both select and on where. It confirms that it really gets the result among the unprocessed data on the select.

Answer (score 1):

To be suere, you can make a test and try:

```
select CONVERT_TZ(event.startingTime,'UTC', city.timezone) as startingTime
left join city on event.cityid = city.id 
where startingTime 
between CONVERT_TZ('2017-01-01 00:00:00','UTC', '+2:00') 
and CONVERT_TZ('2017-01-01 23:59:00','UTC', '+2:00')
```

If you put the convertion in the `where` clause it will filter correctly

Comment: Doing that I get like up to 4 hours ahead. It looks like I have to convert the other way around: CONVERT_TZ('2017-01-01 23:59:00','+2:00', 'UTC')

Comment: What if you do only in one of the branches? lets say only the right, of the AND?

Answer (score 1):

Store as `TIMESTAMP`, not `DATETIME`.  Then, when fetching, the date&time will be converted according to the timezone specified in the client.  No need for `CONVERT_TZ`.

Comment: sometimes the schema can't be modified.